# ArcMap Merging multiple GeoTagged photo points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, photos, geotag

I have a data set of Geo tagged photos that I imported into ArcMap using the GeoTagged Photos to points tool. Some of these photos were taken at the same location but because the Drone moved around a little bit with the wind each photo is represented with a new point that is only a few feet apart. How can I merge these photos so they are represented with a single point on the map?

Comment: What do you want, a stack of points where 1 point =1 photo (easiest option) or a single point that has multiple photos associated (not so easy)?

Comment: A Single point with multiple photos would be ideal. I could work with a stack of points as well.

Comment: Solution might vary depending on the spatial pattern of points. Do you mind please updating your post with a screenshot of typical points' placement. When points grouped it is just a matter of moving attachments from group to single feature in a database